# Cross Thread Exception while adding Items in ListBox VS 2012 C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, listbox, backgroundworker

I have written a little algorithm for Scanning Bluetooth-Devices and add it in my listbox. But I get an Error: Cross Thread Exception.

What I want is to update my listbox continously without any breaks.But a sleep() after an adding would be ok.

Trying it since yesterday with an Backroundworker but it doesnt work and I get an Error while adding. Has Somebody an Idea. I have read something about delegate, somebody has a clue with it?

Here my Code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         this->button1->Enabled=false;
         this->button2->Enabled=true;
         this->toolStripStatusLabel1->Text="Active";
         this->toolStripProgressBar1->Value=100;
         this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();

     }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         this->button1->Enabled=true;
         this->button2->Enabled=false;
         this->toolStripStatusLabel1->Text="Not Active";
         this->toolStripProgressBar1->Value=0;
         this->backgroundWorker1->CancelAsync();
     }
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
             BackgroundWorker^ worker = dynamic_cast <BackgroundWorker^> (sender);

             e->Result = Bluetooth(worker,e);
    }

private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_Complete(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^  e) {

     }

long Bluetooth (BackgroundWorker^ worker, DoWorkEventArgs ^ e){
    if (worker->CancellationPending){
        e->Cancel=true;
    }
    else{
            vector<wstring> vec;
            int m_device_id=0;
            int m_radio_id = 0;
            m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);
            BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);

            m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;
            ::ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
            m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
            m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);

            do{
                wostringstream tmp;
                ++m_device_id;

                //Convert Byte in String
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                  tmp << hex << m_device_info.Address.rgBytes [i];
                  if (i < 5)
                    tmp << L':';
                }                   
                //VectorList
                //vec.push_back(tmp.str());

                listBox1->Items->Add(System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringUni(IntPtr((void*) tmp.str().c_str())));
                Sleep(100);
            }while(BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info));
            BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev);
            BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt);

            long n=0;
            return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: look for help in C# as well as in C++/CLI. The GUI elements you use are part of the .NET framework, and most examples are in C#.

Comment: Yeah I know that - also I have looked for many other examples but no one works really. Thats the reason why I have written it here - maybe some of .Net Experts can help me :-(

Answer (score 1):

Is this WPF or WinForms? With WPF, you can only access controls from the UI thread. To access controls from other threads, call [DispatcherObject.Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416.aspx) or one of the similar methods on the control (all controls inherit from DispatcherObject).

I'm sure there's something similar for WinForms.

Comment: It's WinForms. I'm not a pro grogrammer - sure there is something but don't know what it is...

Comment: OK I looked it up, for WinForms it's Control.Invoke and Control.BeginInvoke.

Comment: I setted the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls= false and it's solved my problem. Should I prefer your solution?

Comment: @user1557170 Yes. **Solving the problem is much and much better than ignoring it!** Your CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls=false solution will result in occasional crashes, due to a race condition. That's one of the hardest thing to debug, and the reason GUI controls should only be accessed by the main thread. Therefor Microsoft added a check to help signalling where the problem could be.

Comment: You are damn right sjoerd! Thanks... Im not a pro programmer to write an ultra solution :-) So on... What else would be the best way to update my listbox continously with Items?

Comment: @user1557170 Instead of adjusting the listbox directly from the wrong thread, call `Invoke(myOwnFunction, stringToDisplay);` to have the system call `myOwnFunction(stringToDisplay)` in the right tread. So if you add a `void myOwnFunction(some_type stringToDisplay) { listBox1->Items->Add(stringToDisplay); }` to your form, it should work. Adjust with correct types and whatever else the compiler requires. (It has been several years since I last touched .NET, and I can't try it out at home, which is why I didn't write an answer)

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx and the example: It creates a thread, then adds something to a listbox using `Invoke`. Your situation is almost the same, except that you use the `BackgroundWorker` (which is better, as it hides the details about creating and managing a worker thread). Especially look at the `myFormControl1->Invoke( myFormControl1->myDelegate, myStringArray );` and `void MyFormControl::AddListItemMethod( String^ myString ) { myListBox->Items->Add( myString ); }`

Comment: Note that `Invoke` expects an array of arguments. Even if you have only one argument, you still have to wrap it in a array (which is done by the `array<Object^>^myStringArray = {myString};` line).

Answer (score 0):

I found it by an accident and wanted to share my solution. :-)

In the constructor I have programmed
     CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls=false; 
that solved my problem :-D I think it's not the best way, but for the first it's ok to update my listbox permanently.

Comment: This is not solving, but ignoring the problem. It may work on the few run you tried, but there will be unexplained crashes now and then (and they always occur at the client's site, and never on your development machine - Murphy's Law).

Comment: Then again, for a simple project for your own amusement, it might be OK. Your solution let you concentrate on the things you want to concentrate on (Although learning how to solve this class of problems is also valuable). Just remember to revisit this piece of code when you run into unexplainable crashes :)

Comment: ok, I'm sure it would be much better if I solve my problem. Has anybody an Idea or can post a good replies which solves my problem?